# Sklearn Linear Regression with Date Data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm having some trouble feeding date data into the sklearn linear regression function.  I understand I need to convert the date data into some form of ordinal numbers but am not familiar enough with python in how to do so!  *Here is what I have*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn import linear_model

data_time = np.asarray(['2017-05-24','2017-05-25','2017-05-26','2017-05-27','2017-05-28','2017-05-29','2017-05-30','2017-05-31','2017-06-01','2017-06-02','2017-06-03','2017-06-04','2017-06-05','2017-06-06','2017-06-07','2017-06-08','2017-06-09','2017-06-10','2017-06-11','2017-06-12','2017-06-13','2017-06-14','2017-06-15','2017-06-16','2017-06-17','2017-06-18','2017-06-19','2017-06-20','2017-06-21']).reshape(-1, 1)
data_count = np.asarray([300.000,301.000,302.000,303.000,304.000,305.000,306.000,307.000,308.000,309.000,310.000,311.000,312.000,230.367,269.032,258.867,221.645,222.323,212.357,198.516,230.133,243.903,244.320,207.451,192.710,212.033,216.677,222.333,208.710]).reshape(-1, 1)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(data_time, data_count)

# Make predictions using the testing set
y_pred = regr.predict(data_time)

plt.title('My Title')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Metric')

plt.scatter(data_time, data_count,  color='black')
plt.plot(data_time, y_pred, color='orange', linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

Naturally this gets the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-05-24'
```

Any help is appreciated! Sidenote: If possible I don't want to stray away from using this numpy array format as I have written a C++ GUI wrapper that generates python code in the background.

Comment: Using `np.datetime64` for `data_time` dtype might help.  Currently they are strings, which can't be used in calculations.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, get: TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[D]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: `regr` may require: `data_time.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(float)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the date conversion using pandas (`pd.to_datetime()`) as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import linear_model

data_time = np.asarray(['2017-05-24', '2017-05-25', '2017-05-26',
                        '2017-05-27', '2017-05-28', '2017-05-29',
                        '2017-05-30', '2017-05-31', '2017-06-01',
                        '2017-06-02', '2017-06-03', '2017-06-04',
                        '2017-06-05', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-07',
                        '2017-06-08', '2017-06-09', '2017-06-10',
                        '2017-06-11', '2017-06-12', '2017-06-13',
                        '2017-06-14', '2017-06-15', '2017-06-16',
                        '2017-06-17', '2017-06-18', '2017-06-19',
                        '2017-06-20', '2017-06-21'])
data_count = np.asarray([300.000, 301.000, 302.000, 303.000, 304.000,
                         305.000, 306.000, 307.000, 308.000, 309.000,
                         310.000, 311.000, 312.000, 230.367, 269.032,
                         258.867, 221.645, 222.323, 212.357, 198.516,
                         230.133, 243.903, 244.320, 207.451, 192.710,
                         212.033, 216.677, 222.333, 208.710])

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': data_time, 'count': data_count})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(df.time.values.reshape(-1, 1), df['count'].reshape(-1, 1))

# Make predictions using the testing set
y_pred = regr.predict(df.time.values.astype(float).reshape(-1, 1))
df['pred'] = y_pred

ax = df.plot(x='time', y='count', color='black', style='.')
df.plot(x='time', y='pred', color='orange', linewidth=3, ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_title('My Title')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Metric')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is easier to have data_time = pd.date_range('2017-05-24', '2017-06-21'), instead of this long array of strings. Converting using pd.to_datetime also becomes unnecessary.

Comment: regr.fit(df.time.values.reshape(-1, 1), df['count'].values.reshape(-1, 1))